# How to update a range of records in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table that I am trying to update a range records, I have tried multiple methods with no luck. Here is the scripts I've tried.

```
UPDATE va_categories SET is_showing = '1' WHERE category_id IS BETWEEN 1076 AND 1412;
UPDATE va_categories SET is_showing = '1' WHERE category_id > '1076' < '1412';
```

The category_id is a Integer field.

I would appreciate an help, banging my head here.

Comment: or put an `AND` and a columnname in the second try. Just basically look up the syntax you need.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this

```
UPDATE va_categories SET is_showing = '1' WHERE category_id  BETWEEN 1076 AND 1412;
```

or

```
 UPDATE va_categories SET is_showing = '1' WHERE category_id > 1076 AND category_id < 1412
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the directive for range in MySQL:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name BETWEEN value1 AND value2;
```

Hence, this works:

```
UPDATE va_categories SET is_showing = '1' WHERE category_id BETWEEN 1076 AND 1412;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the `IS` in `IS BETWEEN`. Or use `WHERE category_id > 1076 AND category_id < 1412`:

```
UPDATE va_categories SET is_showing = '1' WHERE category_id BETWEEN 1076 AND 1412;
UPDATE va_categories SET is_showing = '1' WHERE category_id > 1076 AND category_id < 1412;
```